Issue with Node-PG-Migrate and Incorrect Database Name
I'm using node-pg-migrate for my migrations, and I've set up my .env file with a custom database name, but when I run the migration command, it always tries to connect to a database with my PC's admin username and throws the error that this database does not exist.
I've confirmed that the correct environment variables are being loaded and that the database exists with the correct name. Here’s the error I’m getting:
could not connect to postgres: error: database "<My-pc-username>" does not exist

I've tried running the migration with the correct database name in the DB_NAME field, but it still defaults to my PC username. Does anyone know why it's not picking up the right database or how to resolve this?

If other values are being picked up from your env file then either the setting-name is incorrect or (unlikely) it isn't supported at all. For an actual answer you'll need to supply detalis on the version of node-pg-migrate (ideally with a link to the relevant part of their documentation) and the .env file (hide any passwords) too

I tried following the docs and created a config.json file with the database_url as suggested, but I’m still getting the same error:
could not connect to postgres: error: FATAL: role "undefined" does not exist
It seems like it’s not picking up the database_url even when using the config file.
Any idea what could be causing this?

Sorry, no, because there is no useful detail in your question. However, you have moved from a missing database name to a missing user name. Hopefully you have kept track of all the individual changes you made and can use that to figure it out.
